# JavaFX StringConverter not applying to combo box

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-2

I'm trying to make a combo box table cell in a table in JavaFX.  I have used a string converter so that false displays "No" and true displays "Yes" in the table, and this is working. However, when I click on the cell to edit it, the combo box still shows "false" and "true", as seen below:

[image: screen shot of incorrect behavior]

I am setting up my table cell like this:

```
colPossibleDischarge.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RoomProperty, Boolean>("discharge"));
colPossibleDischarge.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<RoomProperty, Boolean>, TableCell<RoomProperty, Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<RoomProperty, Boolean> call(TableColumn<RoomProperty, Boolean> roomPropertyBooleanTableColumn) {
        return new ComboBoxTableCell<RoomProperty, Boolean>(new YesNoStringConverter(),true,false);
    }
});
```

and my string converter looks like this:

```
public class YesNoStringConverter extends StringConverter<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public String toString(Boolean bool) {
        return (bool?"Yes":"No");
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean fromString(String s) {
        return s.equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing...

This is a [known bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-26824); it is fixed in JavaFX 8. 
If you are locked into JavaFX 2.2 (JDK 7) for now, the workaround would be to roll your own custom cell, which is a bit tedious but not too bad.

Also, though, I think in this exact scenario I'd consider using a CheckBoxTableCell, which is a bit of a nicer user experience for a Yes/No choice than a combo box.